# HowlerJS - trying to get simple mp3 audio file running

Tags: javascript, html, audio, mp3, howler.js

I've been trying to use HowlerJS to play audio files through the browser, however, I'm stuck on the Get Started section of using this tool. Here is my simple file I've been trying to get running:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./jkl.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="play">Play</button>

        <script src="../../src/howler.core.js"></script>
        <script src="../../src/howler.js"></script>
        <script>
            const element = document.getElementById("play");
            element.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

            function myFunction() {
                var sound = new Howl ({
                    src: ['./audio/running_out.mp3']
                });

                sound.play();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to get an audio file to play once the user has clicked on the button element. I made sure that the paths to all the files are correct, and I am able to run the example programs that HowlerJS provided on my browser (Google Chrome). However, once I try to create a simple example, the audio file doesn't play.

Any suggestions or does anybody know what's going on? I'd really appreciate it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can get your code to work on my server but not in the code snippet editor.  Here it is working but with paths changed:
https://viewescape.com/test_howler/test.php

I'd preferably use an onclick within the button itself to call the function, however that's just my preferred use of howler with buttons.

Here is the source:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./jkl.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="play">Play</button>


<script src="https://viewescape.com/test_howler/dist/howler.js"></script>
        <script>
            const element = document.getElementById("play");
            element.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

            function myFunction() {
                var sound = new Howl ({
                    src: ['https://viewescape.com/audio/3secLoop_n.wav'],
                    volume: 0.2,
                    loop:  true
                });

                sound.play();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```